# jQuery animate scrolltop it's not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I'm trying to use the scroll effect using jQuery animate scrolltop but it's not working and I can't figure out why.

My whole code can be found here...  https://codepen.io/andresq820/project/editor/Aogyqr

My navbar has the following links and the jQuery class for each starting with js--

```
 <div class="menu-section">
    <ul class="main-nav js--main-nav">
       <li class="js--scroll-to-main"> <a href="#header">Inicio</a> </li>
       <li class="js--scroll-to-about_us"> <a href="#section-about_us">Nosotros</a> </li>
       <li class="js--scroll-to-services"> <a href="#section-services">Servicios</a> </li>
       <li class="contact-link js--scroll-to-contact_us"> <a href="#section-contact" class="separator">Contactanos</a> </li>
    </ul>    
 </div>
```

I then have each section labeled with the respective class where I want the scroll to land as follows

```
 <section class="section-about_us js--section-about_us" id="section-about_us">

 <section class="section-services js--section-services" id="section-services">

 <section class="section-contact js--section-contact" id="section-contact">
```

My jQuery code is below

```
/* scroll buttons/links */
$('.js--scroll-to-main').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('header').offset().top}, 1000);    
});

$('.js--scroll-to-about_us').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('.js--section-about_us').offset().top}, 1000);    
});

$('.js--scroll-to-services').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('.js--section-services').offset().top}, 1000);    
});

$('.js--scroll-to-contact_us').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('.js--section-contact').offset().top}, 1000);    
});
```

Comment: The code you include in your question works correctly, so the issue is something else. Your codepen example is full of errors in the console so its difficult to tell whats going wrong, but if you are getting any javascript error in your actual code, it will prevent any further javascript from working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to wrap the whole jQuery code inside document.ready function. Then the smooth scrolling effect will work. Hope it'll be help you. Here is the whole code.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  /* scroll buttons/links */
  $('.js--scroll-to-main').click(function(){
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('header').offset().top}, 1000);    
  });

  $('.js--scroll-to-about_us').click(function(){
     
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('.js--section-about_us').offset().top}, 1000);    
  });

  $('.js--scroll-to-services').click(function(){
     
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('.js--section-services').offset().top}, 1000);    
  });

  $('.js--scroll-to-contact_us').click(function(){
     
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('.js--section-contact').offset().top}, 1000);    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-section">
    <ul class="main-nav js--main-nav">
       <li class="js--scroll-to-main"> <a href="#header">Inicio</a> </li>
       <li class="js--scroll-to-about_us"> <a href="#section-about_us">Nosotros</a> </li>
       <li class="js--scroll-to-services"> <a href="#section-services">Servicios</a> </li>
       <li class="contact-link js--scroll-to-contact_us"> <a href="#section-contact" class="separator">Contactanos</a> </li>
    </ul>    
 </div> 
 
 <section class="section-about_us js--section-about_us" id="section-about_us">I then have each section labeled with the respective class where I want the scroll to land as followsI then have each section labeled with the respective class where I want the scroll to land as followsI then have each section labeled with the respective class where I want the scroll to land as followsI then have each section labeled with the respective class where I want the scroll to land as followsI then have each section labeled with the respective class where I want the scroll to land as follows</section>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
 <section class="section-services js--section-services" id="section-services">I then have each section labeled with the respective class where I want the scroll to land as followsI then have each section labeled with the respective class where I want the scroll to land as followsI then have each section labeled with the respective class where I want the scroll to land as followsI then have each section labeled with the respective class where I want the scroll to land as follows</section>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
 <section class="section-contact js--section-contact" id="section-contact">I then have each section labeled with the respective class where I want the scroll to land as followsI then have each section labeled with the respective class where I want the scroll to land as followsI then have each section labeled with the respective class where I want the scroll to land as followsI then have each section labeled with the respective class where I want the scroll to land as follows</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this line `<li class="js--scroll-to-main"> <a href="#header">Inicio</a> </li>` has no section id. Let me use the second as example, then tweak it to your own usage.
Try

```
$('.js--scroll-to-about_us').click(function(){ 
//alert("alert here to see if the link is making contact");
$('#section-about_us').slideDown(1000);
});
```

See if that works.

Comment: The code in the question already works, so this is unnecessary and doesn't help with the actual problem.